# What is the significance of numbers (2,3) mentioned in SOT23?

Tags: semiconductors, packages

Small outline transistor (SOT) packages have certain numbers which tell the package size, for example, SOT23 or SOT323. But what is the meaning of suffix 23 or 323?

Comment: The only significance is that it is a unique identifier. **S**mall **O**utline **T**ransistor (number) 23 (or 323).

Answer (score 12):

While some packages do have numbers that mean something, the TO, DO, SC, SOT, and SOD series are simply serial. SOT-23 is just package number 23 in the JEDEC SOT specifications. There's no significance to the numbers beyond that.

You may occasionally see SOT-23-3 or SOT-23-5 or SOT-23-6; these do have significance, as the last digit is the number of pins on the package. Sometimes SOT-23-5 gets referred to as SOT-25, as well, but this is generally considered incorrect. Similarly for SOT-23-6 being called SOT-26.

Answer (score 1):

SC-70, SOT-323 are smaller package vs SOT-23.

I believe the biggest is SOT-323 has 1.3mm between the 2 legs while SOT-23 has 1.83mm.

Comment: SOT-23: 1.9 according to wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-outline_transistor

Comment: 1.83 typical on the datasheet I was looking at. 1.78mm min to 2.05mm max. 1.83 and 1.9 are both in that range.

Comment: Ok ... just a side question, I want to create a PCB (first) in some time using KiCad, should I worry about these distances, or can I just use a SOT-23 (handsolder) footprint for any SOT-23 component I want to add, or should I check each datasheet  for the exact measurements? Guess the variance doesn't matter that much anyway.

Comment: Generic SOT-23 should be good for most parts as long as you have the recommended footprint for at least one part.  For footprint pad examples see https://www.diodes.com/design/support/packaging/diodes-packaging/diodes-package-outlines-and-pad-layouts/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, going to save that link.